# How to create installable google app script triggers programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api-nodejs-client

I may misunderstand the spec of triggers but let me ask the following question.

I m developing an app that creates a spreadsheet with a container bound script to the spreadsheet. The script has functions that expect to be run by triggers (onEdit or so on). Since the functions have some feature that require authorization and simple triggers cannot run them, "installable trigger" should be used. I don't wanna users to set triggers by themselves so I also wanna create trigger by program when a user open the spreadsheet at the fist time using simple trigger function onOpen(e).

My problem is that installable trigger cannot be created in the simple trigger function like below.

```
function onOpen(e) {
    const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
    const trigger = triggers.find(trigger => trigger.getEventType() === ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT)
    if (!trigger) {
        // ↓error occurs "Exception: ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers を呼び出す権限がありません。"
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').forSpreadsheet('spreadsheetId').onEdit().create()
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to create installable triggers in simple trigger function ? or Google Script API SDK (node.js) can solve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Here a the documentation, although I not sure how it work. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Thanks. I already checked the doc but not solved yet actually.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage. Google Apps Script API cannot install the installable trigger. By this, this cannot be achieved with Node.js. But, I thought that there is a workaround. If you can prepare Web Apps created by Google Apps Script, for example, how about installing the trigger using Web Apps? Web Apps can install the installable trigger. I thought that this might become the workaround for achieving your issue. If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike-san, thanks for your help every time. Well, I solved the problem by adding add-on menu to spreadsheet and letting user click to install the triggers. This solution must not be perfect but acceptable. Again, thank you very much !!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve:

1. Add an add-on menu
2. Let a user click the menu to install "installable triggers"

Other way Tanaike-san raised:

1. Deploy the script as a webApp
2. The app installs "installable triggers"

I didn't try the latter solution but. Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for this, I had exactly the same problem.